# How to overlap appended li items in CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists, z-index, overlap

I have created a number of buttons that when clicked, append and remove li items containing images in a ul parent.

As these li items are not static in the html, they can be added in any order by the user depending on which order they click the buttons. Basically DOM element addition and removal.

```
$(function() {
$(".addToms").click(function () {
    if ($("li").is('#tomato'))
       $("li").remove('#tomato');     
    else
        $("ul").prepend('<li class="centerUL" id="tomato"><img src="tomato.jpg"></li>');
    });
});

$(function() {
$(".addLettuce").click(function () {
    if ($("li").is('#lettuce'))
       $("li").remove('#lettuce');    
    else
        $("ul").prepend('<li class="centerUL" id="lettuce"><img src="lettuce.jpg"></li>');
    });
});
```

It works great.

```
<div class="addToms">tomato</div>
<div class="addLettuce">lettuce</div>

<ul class="centerUL">

</ul>
```

My question is how can I overlap these dynamically created list items which contain images??

I understand how the concept of z-index works, but I can’t set a static position for each li item as I do not know which li items will be added in which order by the user, so any static or numeric value settings will not work I guess.

If anyone can help, cheques in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
ul.centerUL {
   position: relative;
}
```

That sets your `<UL>` as the origin point.

```
.centerUL li {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0
}
```

That positions your `<LI>`

If you want to position your LIs independently you can style them inline as you create them:

```
$("ul").prepend('<li style="'+ someCounter +px'" id="tomato"><img src="tomato.jpg"></li>');
```

Note that IDs are supposed to be unique, your id="tomato" is wrong if you've got more than one element.

Comment: thanks that’s great. Can you help explain what the  ‘+ someCounter +px’” code refers to or means. Apologies I have only been coding for 6 months and am keen to understand the logic.

Comment: At the top of your code: `var someCounter = 0`, then in your click, you can say: `someCounter = someCounter +10`, then it moves down 10px on each new click.

Comment: thanks again. I'm keen to upvote your answer, but I am not able to get the click function to add the new appended li item 10px lower on the screen that it would usually be. I am able to use the inline styling in the append function which is applying and working, but I don't understand how creating a variable will move the element 10px when set inside the inline "style" tags like you suggested. The answer you submitted is exactly what I was looking for and sounds awesome, but I cannot get it to work. It actually stops all the other scripts working at present.